# Meu innertext não funciona em conjunto com a variavel

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eventos DOM</title>
    <style>
      div#area {
        background: rgb(15, 116, 15);
        font: normal 18pt arial;
        color: white;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id='area' onclick="clicar()">
      interaja...
    </div>
    <script>
      function clicar() {
        var a = window.document.querySelector('area').innerText = 'clicou'
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ao usar o onclick era pra aparecer a opção de clicar no Live Server. Alguém consegue achar algum erro no código? procurei e nada. Obrigado, desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando `querySelector`, teria de colocar um `#` para pegar o `id` em questão.
Funciona como seletor CSS, `#` para `id` e `.` para `class`.

```js
function clicar(){ var a = window.document.querySelector('#area').innerText='clicou' }
```

Observe o **#area** em vez de apenas **area**.

Comment: Valeeu, funcionou!